# Why reference's type is class in Java

Tags: java, class, object, reference

In java, `Book c =  new Book()`
here c is reference. Why reference's type be a class name. What is the special reason.?

Comment: Because a reference is not a long or an int.  But of course, if you declare a String you're declaring a reference.

Comment: (A reference is equivalent to a pointer in C/C++.  It is not the thing itself but rather the address of the thing.)

Comment: because it provides compile time check

Comment: And Java is a strongly typed language, meaning that references must carry the type of the object they represent.

Answer (score 2):

```
Book c =  new Book(); // c points to a Book object. Now, if you declare c as an int, it means that c points to an int.
```